# animateWithDuration in Swift - Could not find member 'CurveEaseOut'

Tags: swift, animatewithduration

I get the following error when attempting to pass a variable in to my animation in Swift:

```
Could not find member 'CurveEaseOut'
```

My code seems fine if I type the degrees in manually:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: NSTimeInterval(0.0), options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
    }, completion: nil)
```

But I have the issue if I attempt to use a variable:

```
var turn = Double()

turn = 180.0

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: NSTimeInterval(0.0), options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((turn * CGFloat(M_PI)) / turn)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Perhaps it's my use of Double()? I've tried various different types and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with .CurveEaseOut. The problem i think is within the closure.

Try this

```
var turn:CGFloat = 180.0
```

If the error remains then arrowImage is optional and you have to use if let to unwrapped it

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: NSTimeInterval(0.0), options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        if let ai = self.arrowImage {
             ai.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((turn * CGFloat(M_PI)) / turn)
       }
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, Christos. It was an optional, so I needed to use if let to unwrap it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do two things. You could either

```
let turn: CGFloat = 180.0
```

or

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(turn) * CGFloat(M_PI)) / CGFloat(turn))`

Since Swift is type safe it's expecting a CGFloat passed to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you're using the variable turn. You're using turn inside a closure and you must use self.turn because turn is declared outside the scope of the animation closure.

Weird but that's how it is :\